# What is the difference between "unused parameter" and "unused type parameter" (Resharper)

Tags: c#, ide, resharper

[image]

What is the difference between them ? can some one please give me an example of "unused parameter" and "unused type parameter" ?

And another question, even i the resharper finds things that are errors, the project still builds, how can i make vs to fail the build if resharper finds errors

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: "And another question..." usually doesn't work that well. Stack overflow is really good at getting one specific question answered at a time, but people here are likely to ignore your second question when posting two questions in one. Conversely, there is no harm in posting two separate questions. You may want to do that :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i have many related questions and i don't want to spam..

Answer (score 4):

Given the below:

```
void SomeMethod<someTypeParameter>(someType someParameter)
{
  // doing all kinds of things, but not using someTypeParameter and someParameter
}
```

The unused type parameter would be the generic parameter, `someTypeParameter` (inside the `<>`) and the unused parameter would be `someParameter`.

Answer (score 4):

Unused parameter:

```
void Go(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm totally ignoring the 's' parameter");
}
```

Unused type parameter:

```
public static void Go<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm totally ignoring the `T` generic parameter");
}
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your second question, looks like that's not possible - but there's a discussion [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/265285?tstart=30) on making ReSharper part of your build process. It's an old thread, but it continues pretty recently.